# BibTeX does no find basic files

Tags: bibtex, texlive-2018

If I run bibtex it says that it cannot find the file unsrt.bst

```
I couldn't open style file unsrt.bst
```

This is strange because unsrt.bst this is one of the basic files of bibtex. Anyway, the man page of bibtex says that it first looks in the path defined by the variable BSTINPUTS. So if I set

```
export BSTINPUTS=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base
```

then bibtex does find the unsrt.bst file. But then bibtex claims that it cannot find my bib file

```
I couldn't open database file references.bib
```

which, however, is in the same directory!

So obviously bibtex has some severe problems to find the standard files and to find files in the same directory.

It seems that there is something wrong with my installation. For me it is no satisfying solution to manually set the path, since there are a lot of standard bst folders with texlive, not just .../bst/base.

I installed texlive via the [quick install guide](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

And I already tried

```
tlmgr install --reinstall bibtex
```

but it did not change anything.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Did you follow, in particular, the instructions for "Post-install: setting PATH" in the quick install guide? You could probably also take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/105447.

Comment: Yes I did. Otherwise all the commands like "bibtex" would not work.

Comment: What is the result of `kpsewhich unsrt.bst` on your terminal?

Comment: No output. But when I set the variable BSTINPUTS then it says "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/unsrt.bst"

Comment: So it seems to be a path problem indeed. Though I've never faced the need to specify `BSTINPUTS` manually myself, so I don't have much clue what might be going wrong. Let's see if someone else has some experience with it. You could though add some more information to your question which might be useful: e.g. your distro, if there are any other parallel installations of a TeX distribution in your system, exactly how you are setting your path, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There are in this case three separate environment variables to consider

◦ TEXINPUTS tells LaTeX where to find sty (style) files.
◦ BSTINPUTS tells BibTeX where to find bst (bibliography style) files.
◦ BIBINPUTS tells BibTeX where to look for bib (bibliography database) files.

By default to reduce issues you can keep all the necessary files in the same directory where you are processing your documents.

Or make symbolic links to them with the UNIX command ln -s.

Alternatively they can be set in a variety of different ways.

For windows users it is simplest to set them in the "System" environment (unless you are on a shared system, in which case you may need to set them per user)

A list for MiKTeX users without advice is here https://docs.miktex.org/manual/envvars.html

One very terse users guide is available [here](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~wjh/tex/documents/environmental.pdf) and another description here https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/webpub/Installing_LaTeX_BibTeX_Input.html

In some cases the environmental paths **MAY** include more than one location (subject to system syntax ; for windows : for others?) such as
command to set EnvVar=FirstDir;SecondDir;Default
Don't forget to add the default last !

However if it does not appear to work (especially due to other overrides) then remove the confusion of multiple locations.

Others have commented however I cant verify
"Remember, if you start an editor from a menu, then any setting in bashrc is ignored. You need to add them to .profile, log out and log in again. If you start texworks from the command line it will know the setting from bashrc"

Also note in Windows and some other systems setting (especially using setx / set) environment variables may not always "Stick" simply by re-logging in again. **It may require a reboot** to take permanent effect.